# Loop through Snowflake array

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm looking for a way to get data from this Collection.

The data looks like:

```
  '0000000' => GuildMember {
  guild:
   Guild {
     members: [Object],
     id: '000000',
     name: 'Zombie',
     _rawVoiceStates: [Object] },
  user:
   User {
     id: '0000000',
     username: 'Orc',
  _roles: [ '0000' ],
  nickname: 'Orc',
  joinedTimestamp: 00000,
  lastMessageID: null },

  '0000000' => GuildMember {
  guild:
   Guild {
     members: [Object],
     id: '000000',
     name: 'Zombie',
     _rawVoiceStates: [Object] },
  user:
   User {
     id: '0000001',
     username: 'Orc1',
  _roles: [ '0000' ],
  nickname: 'Orc',
  joinedTimestamp: 00000,
  lastMessageID: null },
  _array: null,
  _keyArray: null }
```

My current loop is:

```
var user;
for(var u in test.members){
   user = test.members[u];
    console.log("["+u+"] "+user.username);
}
```

It currently kicks back a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'user' of null`

I originally thought this the data was an array, but it's not according to the Discord.js docs, but I'm still not sure how to pull the username data from the collection.

Any help would be helpful.

Comment: maybe do a pastebin of `console.log(JSON.stringify(test.members, null, 2);)` we can't really examine the data structure of `test.members` like that :(

Comment: Kicks back {
  "_array": null,
  "_keyArray": null
}

Comment: which means its empty object not array, where do you get the data from OP from then?

Comment: console.log(test.members); outputs the data I posted.

Comment: well this has nothing todo with arrays and for.. in then. I guess you try reading into the discord.js api a bit more and see if you can pull your users and names from there. sorry that i wasn't of much help

Comment: Yep, not an array. It's a Data Collection. I'll do some more research. Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Now i looked into the discord.js API and i think what u got todo is something like this (assuming test is your guild object):

```
test.members.forEach(function(guildMember, guildMemberId) {
   console.log(guildMemberId, guildMember.user.username);
})
```

If that doesn't work try along the lines of:

```
var membersArray = test.members.array();

for(var guildMemberId in membersArray) {
   console.log(guildMemberId, membersArray[guildMemberId].user.username);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'user' of null

means your `user` variable is null which means `test.members[u]` is null.
Try logging the `test.members` first and see if its filled.

`user.user.username`

is probably wrong. As it looks it should be just `user.username`

Comment: test.members is an array, it's how I got the array structure for the OP, with console.log. But you are right, u is coming back undefined. any idea what's wrong with that?

Comment: `var u;` in the first line does a `var u = undefined;` wich gets used instead of the provided `u` of the `for.. in`, so delete it. @Carl

Comment: I think I posted bad info. I updated the data output from my test.members.

Comment: So if test.members is really an array.
`for(var u in test.members){
    console.log(u, test.members[u]);
}`
should net you something, i don't know how to get 'u == undefined' there. @Carl

Comment: Kicks back a 
_array null
_keyArray null

Comment: is this javascript? ^^ what environment is this?

Comment: Node.js and Discord.js