# array() function returns an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have a problem with discord.js
I'm trying to get all the players that have a role with `let gplayers = games_array[0].role.members`, but since it returns an object that's like `{"123" => GuildMember {}, "456" => GuildMember {} ...}` and I need only the `"123"` and `"456"` objects I tried to use `let gplayers = games_array[0].role.members.array()` and then using `gplayers[i]`m but it didn't work.
I tried to check what was going wrong and I found out that `gplayers` was an object, even if I used the `array()` function.

`console.log('Members: ', JSON.stringify(games_array[0].role.members, null, 4))` logs `Members: {}`

What can I do to store my objects in an array?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally found the solution: I used this method

```
collection.forEach(function(guildMember) {
  //guildMember is now a User object, and I can do everything using properties
  console.log(guildMember.user.username);
})
```

Solution thread: [Loop through Snowflake array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43233040/loop-through-snowflake-array-discord-js)

Answer (score 0):

You can just loop through the keys (in this case "123", "456", etc.) and push their values into a new array.

```
let players = [];
let members = games_array[0].role.members;
for(key in members) {
    players.push(members[key]);
}
```

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't work. I logged `gplayers` and it said that's a Collection, in fact there are only `'123' => GuildMember {things}` and there isn't any property and value like `a: '123'`

Comment: Alright. Do us a favor and log out what you get from members using `console.log('Members: ', JSON.stringify(games_array[0].role.members, null, 4))` This will show you what members looks like in JSON format with some nice spacing. Take whatever it prints out and add it to your post so we can see what the data looks like and we can help you better :)

Comment: Post more of your code. If we can get and play with the data, we can help better.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the for-in loop to loop through the properties of the returned object

```
var gplayers = games_array[0].role.members;
var key;
for (key in gplayers) {
    // do whatever you want here
    // you can access the key's associated value as gplayers[key]    
}
```

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't work. I logged `gplayers` and it said that's a Collection, in fact there are only `'123' => GuildMember {things}` and there isn't any property and value like `a: '123'`

Answer (score -1):

you may use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) in recent engines:

`let players = Object.values(games_array[0].role.members)`

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't work. I logged `gplayers` and it said that's a Collection, in fact there are only `'123' => GuildMember {things}` and there isn't any property and value like `a: '123'`